# How do I find out the coordinates, interpolating across an angled line?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

Suppose I know the coordinates of $A$ and $B$. The angle $X$ does **not** mean the total angle between the red lines, but rather how far along the angle that the purple line is. What is the easiest way to calculate the coordinates of $P$ then?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the angle that $OA$ makes at the origin with $\theta=\text{atan2}(A_x,A_y)$.  Then the angle that $OP$ makes is $\phi=\theta-x$ and the equation of $OP$ is $y=x \tan \phi$.  The equation of $AB$ is $y-A_y=\frac{B_y-A_y}{B_x-A_x}(x-A_x)$  Two equations in two unknowns and $y$ eliminates easily.